# Unable to find NuGet package version in TFS build?

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package-restore, build-agent

I am using TFS 2017 and NuGet Installer - 0 task for NuGet restore in build definition but getting an error **unable to find version**.

It's using below command for restoring packages

```
D:\agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive D:\agent\_work\42\s\xyz\xyz.sln -Verbosity Detailed

Unable to find version '3.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'.
2020-06-15T14:50:36.6499535Z Unable to find version '5.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost'.
2020-06-15T14:50:36.6499535Z Unable to find version '5.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core'.
2020-06-15T14:50:36.6499535Z Unable to find version '5.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'.
2020-06-15T14:50:36.6499535Z Unable to find version '5.2.7' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
```

But when I run same above command manually on the agent it's working fine also tried updating NuGet task version.

Comment: Hi @Naveen have you tried to tick the include nuget.org search in the nuget task.  I'm not sure of the exact name but there should be a option to check so it looks in nuget.org

Comment: Hi @Etienne thanks I have tried this solution and it's working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unable to find version '3.2.7' of package xxx

Agree with Etienne. The versions of these packages can be found in `nuget.org`.

When you use the `Nuget Restore task` in TFS2017, you could try the following methods to use the nuget.org.

1. Use the `Nuget Restore task` V1. Select the `Use Packages from nuget.org` option.

[image]

2. If you use the nuget.config file , you could add the `nuget.config` package source in the file.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <clear />
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"protocolVersion="3" />
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>`

Here is a doc about [nuget.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops#specifying-sources-in-nugetconfig).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem on one of our projects since this morning (16 June 2020) and we needed to upgrade our Nuget.exe.
I can see you're using Nuget 3.3 and the current recommended version is 5.5.1.

It seems to be installed by a npm package.

```
D:\agent\_work\_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe
```

The latest version is here:
https://www.nuget.org/downloads

Replacing it with the latest stable version worked.

EDIT:
The reason old Nuget versions no longer works is because GitHub dropped support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN9sF.png (can't submit pictures yet)]

Comment: Hi @Jernej thanks for the solution, it's working fine.